# Не могу развернуть приложение python(django) на heroku

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, heroku, развертывание

Я новичок в django, по тому делаю всё как написано в книге, но столкнулся с проблемой. Я не могу развернуть свой проект на heroku, потому что возникает проблема со сборкой статических файлов. 
Мой файл setting.py :

```
"""
Django settings for learning_log project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '8ucxs#ss33+r^qb&u+zbelvob(2t*@zadu6yl)fm7$sq%0^a7-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # other
    'bootstrap3',
    # custom apps:
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_log.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_log.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# My Settings

LOGIN_URL = '/users/login'

BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')   

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

При локальной сборке всё работает как надо, выдаёт: "0 static files copied to 'C:\envs\projects\learning_log\learning_log\static', 119 unmodified." (я работаю на windows, если это важно.)
При вводу git push heroku master выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

Хотя переменная STATIC_ROOT у меня в файле есть. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Поробуйте заменить `STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'` на `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`. После блока `if` выведите `print(STATIC_ROOT)`, чтобы узнать, что там вообще хранится.

Comment: C:\envs\projects\learning_log\learning_log\static
Выводит вот это. Путь к папке со статическими файлами

Comment: Ну так это локально выводит `...\static`, а в деплое-то, наверное, срабатывает код в `if` блоке и `STATIC_ROOT` становится `staticfiles`?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить условие в `if` на `cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp'`